# Text slider - can't change/remove speed

Tags: javascript, html

Simple Text Slider from [here](http://www.jqueryscript.net/rotator/Simple-Text-Slider-Rotator-with-jQuery-CSS.html)

Can't change speed or remove automatic slide [here](http://files.elamed.com.pl/WWP/testowy/index.html#speakers)

button "Więcej o prelegentach" opens full screen layer where slider is placed.

Trying to change speed in

```
 var speed = 5000;
```

but didn't helped. Even tried to remove:

```
var run = setInterval(rotate, speed);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you provide code samples, or more preferably a http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: the same script as here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27451066/using-a-jquery-slider-for-text-instead-of-images
but mine is placed in full screen popup layer. Maybe thats the problem, but it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try loading the jquery before you load any other script (on your page it is loaded after few others, including the slider script).

I think that will solve it, right now your page gives back error:

> ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Edit:
Here's the html structure for that plugin.

```
  <div id="slides">
    <ul>
      <li class="slide">
        <div class="quoteContainer">
          <p class="quote-phrase">
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="authorContainer">
          <p class="quote-author">
          </p>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="slide">
        <div class="quoteContainer">
          <p class="quote-phrase">
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="authorContainer">
          <p class="quote-author">
          </p>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="slide">
        <div class="quoteContainer">
          <p class="quote-phrase"></p>
        </div>
        <div class="authorContainer">
          <p class="quote-author">
          </p>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
 </div>
```

Comment: hmm, the only difference now I see is faster loading, but thanks :)

Comment: I think you didn't do it, in your code jquery is still loaded at the bottom of the page, where you have commented <!--== Javascript Files ==--> (2nd one). Move it to the head and paste it before <script src="js/snap.svg-min.js"></script>, right now your page still throws error $ is not defined which means you either have mistyped the jquery path or you are loading it after some other jquery plugins. If you are doing it on you local please be so kind and upload it to live.

Comment: Once you do it you should be able to change the speed changing the value of var speed = 5000; (var speed = 999999999; in your case :D ) change it to 10 maybe.

Comment: sorry, didn't noticed connection error. Now its updated with jquery in top, and 99999 in speed.

Comment: And? Is it working? Set the var speed to 1, it will be moving almost non stop, you will see the difference, I got it to work on my local with no problems.

Comment: Hmm it's not working local neither on serwer for me :( could be cache or something? testen on 2 browsers ff and chrome...

Comment: Okay, there are errors in your HTML as well. To use that plugin you have to create one unordered list inside <div id="slides">, then you add <li> tags with class "slide". You are closing <ul> tag each time so you are creating many lists instead of one. Also don't close the containing div with id slides each time, it has to contain the entire list.

Comment: I have just added template html code you for that plugin, check my edit to the answer, you will see what I mean.

Comment: I've changed that coz it was appearing all slides in one.
Now it looks like that http://files.elamed.com.pl/WWP/testowy/
showing only first and last element, with still the same speed

Comment: I don't see any changes made on your site. Right now instead of having one list with few quotes you have many single lists with one quote so if you change the var speed nothing happens since there are no slides to change. Change the html and run it only with jquery loaded and the slider script. If you will still have the problem with how it appears it will mean there are still errors to correct but this time in css.

Comment: Yep, you have errors in css. Add overflow: hidden; to containing div in style.css, the one with ID "slides" (apart from changing the rest of the things).

Comment: As I look further into your code it seems your slider isn't working at all, at the present moment you are changing slides with different plugin (owl carousel), so either decide yourself which one you want to do or rewrite the code. If you want to keep using owl carousel look in the js to edit options, right now you have the transition set to 800ms. When you change the value of var speed nothing happens since it's different plugin that doesn't even seem to work at the moment. You could tidy up your code, would be much easier to help you.

Comment: Okey, thank you! I will try to tidy up code later. Now I've changed my css and options in owl.carousel and it works for me ;)